# ../../pathToAFile.css dosen't work with Webpack

Tags: webpack, webpack-2, webpack-style-loader

I would like to ask you a question. Today I found strange behavior using Webpack v3+. When I use this ../pathToAFile.css or ../pathToAFile.js or anything like this in my main.js file everything is fine, I get no errors to load any file but if I try to add another level like ../../pathToAFile.css I get the error. Does anyone know why? Do I need an additional module or anything?

Comment: Not related to module, it suppose to be a real path to a real file, if the file is not exists it will fail.

Comment: ok thx, solved. I realized what I did wrong.